# How to add heading to a Linear Layout

Tags: android, border

I have to create A GUI like below. I have used LinearLayout and created the border around it.I have to insert the header text between the border. Any idea how to do this.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout>)
    <LinearLayout with border>
    <TextView with white background>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The TextView should appear above the linearlayout covering the border with his white background. You could position it using margins.

Answer (score 1):

use relative layout as parent and put all your linearlayout code under relative layout. Then add textview in relative layout and mention that textview is on top and give marign.

```
  <RelativeLayout>
     <TextView android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_margin="20dip/>
     <LinearLayout>
                // here is your linear layout
     </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout to overlap the line, you can't do that on Linearlayout